# Is it possible to get pixels from OpenGL buffer at the original size?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a 4K project using OpenGL. So all my images are 4K based and it renders ok on my full-screen 1080p computer. OpenGL just resizes nicely without problems. But I want to use something like glReadPixels() to read the buffer but from the 4K origin. So far I couldn't figure out if this is even possible. Not sure what happens with the GPU frame buffer when it resizes, I guess it just keeps the buffer resized to 1080p making it impossible to fetch the original 4k content? If that's the case, I will do something else, but had to ask before I venture into some extra code. ;-) Thank you.

Comment: One thing I could do is use glReadPixels and just up-scale the image from the whole thing is scaled-down, and not rescale when the windows is in 4K. Just need to do the math correctly for that. But I really hope I could fetch the original 4K buffer, if possible.

Comment: Maybe I will have to take a different approach. I need this so I can fetch the background before drawing something on top of it. Like a KNOB, for instance. So maybe I will have to come up with my own buffered-layers that has the backgrounds that are 4K. I will figure something out, I guess. If the above is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [framebuffer object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) to render your scene at the resolution you like and read back the data from there. If you still want the "live preview" in the window, just blit the FBO contents to your default framebuffer (and scale them down in that step).

Comment: Thanks, that sure works, but I'm trying to avoid having to redraw the whole screen again. I could just redraw the portion of the skin that needs redrawing, but that would be some work. I will figure something out. The best option is still to just use glReadPixels and resize to the right size. This only happens when you open a menu or a modal window anyway. ;-)

Comment: "but I'm trying to avoid having to redraw the whole screen again" not sure what you mean by that, but the only overhead this approach brings is the additional blit, and that won't cost much